# What's it called when someone insults you for not knowing something that you've never learnt or that's not in your field?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

For example, let's say I'm a physicist, so I'm not stupid. But, I'm talking to someone who is an accountant and they insult me for not knowing accounting jargon or how to do things involved in their field during a conversation.

Comment: Does the accountant know that you're a physicist?

Comment: This is not specific to your description, but a [cheap shot](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cheap%20shot) is an insult that is unfair or takes advantage of someone's weakness.

Answer (score 5):

*Arrogance*

From Merriam-Webster:

*an attitude of **superiority** manifested in an overbearing manner or in presumptuous claims or assumptions*

Clearly the guy is talking down to you, acting **superiorly**. Often this comes from a feeling of inferiority.

Answer (score 5):

They are being **presumptuous** and **condescending**.  You might call them **pompous**

Answer (score 3):

It’s a *gratuitous* insult:

> 3. Unnecessary or unwarranted; unjustified: gratuitous criticism.

From AHD https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=gratuitous

Answer (score 1):

A relevant concept is the **curse of knowledge**.

According to the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_knowledge),

> The curse of knowledge is a cognitive bias that occurs when an individual, communicating with other individuals, unknowingly assumes that the others have the background to understand.

Of course, the individual in question takes it a step further and insults you for not knowing the concepts he assumes you do. So, calling it a cognitive bias instead of toxic arrogance might be a bit too kind.

Answer (score -1):

9 people out of 10 will say a—hole. There isn’t a single separate word for this form of a—holiness, or every other form thereof, because their number is infinite.

Comment: That's certainly an implication of what this guy did, but it is not the most apt description for the given circumstances. There are many ways to be an asshole and the OP is only one.